# Printing % character attached to floating number

Tags: c++, c++17

So Let's say I am overloading OS operator and I want to have some sort of table of values divided into columns looking like this:

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│      X        │         Y.           │ Z.          │ value        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
```

and below I am printing those Values using stream:

```
<< std::setw(13) << std::noshowpoint << value << "%" << "|" << endl;
```

how can I do this so the output of let's say value equal to 5 will be printed as 5%

I tried to use to_string method but results were overriding noshowpoint operator.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you just showed?

Comment: Let's say that I print value = 5 which is a float type. the number is aligned to left and the percent automatically is aligned to the right next to the end of column. I want the % character to be right next to the number.

Comment: For a table of values there's no need for the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the string for the value and percent sign.

Then use that string with the formatting.

You can do the first part using a string output stream. And you can combine it into a single statement:

```
std::cout << std::setw(13)
          << (std::ostringstream{ } << std::noshowpoint << value << '%').str()
          << "|\n";
```